# Return records after doing some manipulation on them

Tags: sql, database, function, view

I'm creating a web service that takes a mobile number in fixed format (+country code rest of the number ) and I need to return some data based on that number.

The problem is the mobile numbers stored in a table and it don't have any validation or consistent format. For example :

1- having the same format passed in web service. (no problem)

2- having just the mobile number without country code (country code exists in another column so I can concatenate)

3- start with zero then +country code ...

5- empty

... and many other cases.

What I want to do now is doing some work on them to create a similar format to the one passed in the web service and create maybe a new table (view) then doing the comparison to increase the probability of having a result.

I have no idea how I can do this. I read about something called valued-table function but they saying you can't use if-else statement with them which - in my case - I need them the most

(if (mobile number) starts with +country code .. do nothing on it

else if (mobile number) start with 0 remove it

else if (mobile number) doesn't start with +country code concatenate with the 
  other column .... etc)

I know the situation is messed up , But unfortunately I had to work on this kind of database and it has many issues.

Any suggestions or ideas will be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could made use of Stored Procedures. Different from a view, it allows you to write a block of code, utilizing loops and conditions.